# Get photo file with metadata from album photo

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

It is possible to retrieve photo file from the album photo with metadata (IPTC)?
I've tried UIImagePickerController to get UIImage and when I save it to a file, it doesn't contain any metadata information.
There is a way to get the original photo file with ALAsset library?

Comment: this might help you to retrive the metadata http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_Information_Keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with AssetsLibrary:

```
- (void)savePhoto:(NSURL*) url <br
{
    NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetLibrary assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
        NSString* originalFileName = [[asset defaultRepresentation] filename];
        NSString *path = [applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:originalFileName];
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
        NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
        //NSLog(@"%@",data);
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *err) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
    }];
}
```